# Jquery how to select elements below an id/class without being the parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to make a button that toggles every `<p>` below it.

Here is the HTML:

```
<p>SHOW</p>
<p>SHOW</p>
<p>SHOW</p>

<a id="hc-more-info">MORE INFO</a>

<p>HIDE</p>
<p>HIDE</p>
<p>HIDE</p>
<ul> ... <ul>
```

jQuery (this is what I got so far) How do I start with them hiden?

```
jQuery('#hc-more-info').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).parent().nextAll('p, ul').toggle();
    });
```

Any help would be very appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: $('#toggle-below-button').nextAll('p').toggle();

Comment: Add the css style to them: `<p style="display: none;">...</p>`

Comment: Have you solved your question?

Comment: I ended up hidden from on jquery too. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('#hc-more-info').click(function(){   
     jQuery(this).parent().nextAll('p').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Its not working. Check it out at: [link](http://arisedevelop.com/historicorps/main-projects-page/?ee=77)

Comment: In your page jQuery is referred to as `jQuery`, not `$`. So I updated the answer.

Comment: I already fixed that. Its something else its not triggering. Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: The button id is `hc-more-info`. Updated again

Comment: Your code its working but how would start with them I hiden?

Comment: You can add this css style to them: `<p style="display: none;">...</p>`

Answer (score 1):

Can use [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) which will include all siblings that follow current element

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#toggle-below-button').click(function(){        
       var $btn = $(this), showMore = !$btn.hasClass('show-all');
       $btn.toggleClass('show-all')
            .text( showMore  ? 'LESS INFO' :'MORE INFO')
            .nextAll()
            .toggle();       
    });
});
```

Comment: Its not working. Check it out at: [link](http://arisedevelop.com/historicorps/main-projects-page/?ee=77)

Comment: works fine here  https://jsfiddle.net/rj4e8bw2/1  Did you put that code inside a jQuery ready handler?

Comment: I did. But updated the id to my real one (the one on my question, it was just a dummy id). look: `jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   jQuery('#hc-more-info').click(function(){   
     jQuery(this).nextAll('p').toggle();
});



});code`

Comment: The button id is `hc-more-info`. Updated again

Comment: you oversimplified the sample html. When you figure the proper structure out update the question. we shouldn't have to go off site to sort this issue out

Comment: I understand, that is why i made my samples to be simple. I updated the id, that is not the reason why its not working

Comment: for now try inserting in my code `.parent()` before `.nextAll()`

Comment: now its changing the text (More / Less) but not toggling all the <p> tags

Comment: This is the wrong way to debug an SO answer...working in your live page with many many scripts being loaded. Update the jsfiddle link I made with ***real structure*** and code you are using. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101241/discussion-between-marcio-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0):

You can use $('p') as a selector

**EDIT**

Forgive me for not understanding before until the comment. You can use the .next method too but in my view a better practice would be to assign some class to the elements below and then toggle like $('p.toggle') to control it.

Comment: this will select all p before or after the button OP wants after button